# PHP code disappears after copying a file from a server to another

Tags: php

I tried to use different php codes to copy a file (original.php) from a server to another.
Here are codes i tried to use:

Code 1:

```
 <?
 $file = "http://mysiteurl.com/original.php";
 $newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/copiedfile.php';

 if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
     echo "Copy success!";
 }else{
     echo "Copy failed.";
 }
 ?>
```

Code 2:

```
 <?
 $remotefile="original.php";
 $folder="/test/";
 $srcfile1 = fopen("$remotefile", "r");
 $namefile=basename($remotefile);
 if (!($fp1 = fopen($folder.$name,"w")));
 while ($contents = fread( $srcfile1, 8192 )) {
 fwrite( $fp1, $contents, strlen($contents) );
 }
 fclose($srcfile1);
 fclose($fp1);
 echo"FILE TRANSFERRED";
 ?>
```

in both cases original.php and the copied file aren't same. In the copied file php codes are all disappeared.

here is an example of origninal.php

```
 <?php
 ... some php code
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
 <head>
 ... come html code
```

the copiedfile.php is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
 <head>
 ... come html code
```

How can i fix the issue?

Comment: You can't read the source of the PHP file over http. You have to access the original file via FTP or network share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

The server will parse the phpfile that you want to copy so all php code will be gone. By using copy on an url (or file_get_contents) you will actually ask the server to serve the file for you as you where asking with with a browser.

And you should be glad it does otherwise it would be pretty easy for people to steal the code and find any secrets therein.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Anyway, in my case i wanted to my own file from a server to another. Far away to steal other's codes. :)